# Javascript array intersection - performance issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filtering, intersection

I'm trying to match nested elements of big js arrays, it's starting as simple:

*single-ids:*

```
var singles = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "names": [ {name: 'Mark', s: true}, {name: 'Tom', s: true}, {name: 'Karl', s: false} ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "names": [ {name: 'David', s: true}, {name: 'Mark', s: true} ]
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "names": [ {name: 'Karl', s: false}, {name: 'Tom', s: true}, {name: 'Oliver', s: true}, {name: 'Mark', s: true} ]
  }
]
```

The next step is find common "names" of each these objects with "id" in just two of them, like this:

*double-ids:*

```
[
  {
    "id": "1|2",
    "names": [ {name: 'Mark', s: true} ] // Mark is common element of  1 and 2 "single-ids"
  },
  {
    "id": "1|3",
    "names": [ {name: 'Tom', s: true}, {name: 'Karl', s: false}, {name: 'Mark', s: true} ] // Tom, Karl and Mark are common elements of  1 and 3 "single-ids"
  }
]
```

The last step, is finding common "names" in just three elements, like this:

*treble-ids:*

```
[
  {
    "id": "1|2|3",
    "names": [ {name: 'Mark', s: true} ] // Mark is common element of  1, 2 and 3 "single-ids"
  }
]
```

I have written javascript code which is processing my base array, which has over 3000 elements (single-ids), "names" array can contain from 2 to 20+ elements, so it's making huge amount of posibilities to occur in "double-ids" array - after 5secs of processing/matching these 3000~ "single-ids", my "double-ids" array contains 64458 elements.

Fine, 5 seconds - not bad, but its getting hard when It's matching "treble-ids" - its taking long time, and finally my code crashed (memory leak, 8GB of RAM NodeJS droplet).

There is my code: (using lodash filter)

```
var currentset = {
  singles: [],
  doubles: [],
  trebles: []
}

var singles = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "names": [ {name: 'Mark', s: true}, {name: 'Tom', s: true}, {name: 'Karl', s: false} ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "names": [ {name: 'David', s: true}, {name: 'Mark', s: true} ]
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "names": [ {name: 'Karl', s: false}, {name: 'Tom', s: true}, {name: 'Oliver', s: true}, {name: 'Mark', s: true} ]
  }
]

await Promise.all(singles.map(async (single) => {
  let doubleds = _.filter(singles, (sen) => {

    let pts = 0
    if (single.id !== sen.id) pts += 1 // skip the currently processed item
    let ctr = _.filter(single.names, de => sen.names.findIndex(ge => ge.name == de.name) > -1) // find if element has any common name with names from our current element
    if (ctr.length > 0) pts += 1
    return pts == 2 // return if it's not current item and it has at least one common name with it

  }).map((dub) => {
    let nammys = _.filter(dub.names, name => single.names.findIndex(ge => ge.name == name.name) > -1)
    common = _.filter(single.names, de => nammys.findIndex(ge => ge.name == de.name) > -1) // find exact common names
    if (common.length < 1) return // dont return if 0 commons

    return {
      id: `${single.id}|${dub.id}`,
      names: common
    }

  }).filter(el => el !== undefined).forEach((dubel) => { // filter 0 common elements (returned undefined)
    currentset.doubles.push(dubel) // Here we have 'double-ids' objects and I'm pushing them to external array

    // below I'm matching third ID's names by comparing my double-ids names with another singles (looking for common names)
    let trebles = _.filter(singles, (sen) => {
      let pts = 0
      if ((dubel.id.split('|')[0] !== sen.id) && (dubel.id.split('|')[1] !== sen.id)) pts += 1 // skipping single-ids of actually matched ids

      let ctr = _.filter(sen.names, de => dubel.names.findIndex(ge => ge.name == de.name) > -1) // checking if my double-id has common names with another single-id

      if (ctr.length > 0) pts += 1

      return pts == 2

    }).map((treb) => {
      // below I'm finding exact common names between my double-id object and matched third 'single-id' element
      let nammys = _.filter(treb.names, name => dubel.names.findIndex(ge => ge.name == name.name) > -1)
      common = _.filter(dubel.names, de => nammys.findIndex(ge => ge.name == de.name) > -1)

      if (common.length < 1) return

      return {
        id: `${dubel.id}|${treb.id}`,
        names: common
      }
    }).filter(ei => ei !== undefined).forEach(tre => currentset.trebles.push(tre)) // filtering 0 commonds & extracting to external array

  })

}))
```

Probably the "treble-ids" will be really huge array, also I have noticed that at first filtering It's looping 3000~ times, then It's multipling by 64k when matching 'treble-ids'. I think it's the main problem.

Is there any better approach to optimize this operation?
I Was trying a lot of different ways and get stuck with no more ideas.

Comment: Having a faster algorithm won't make any difference against a bad formatted data structure. Think about the origin of the problem (performances) and answer to this question: are you sure you need to elaborate THAT many items simultaneously? Couldn't you delegate the operation instead or think about another more efficient data structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `map` and `filter` in a recursive function like so:

```js
var singles = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "names": [ {name: 'Mark', s: true}, {name: 'Tom', s: true}, {name: 'Karl', s: false} ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "names": [ {name: 'David', s: true}, {name: 'Mark', s: true} ]
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "names": [ {name: 'Karl', s: false}, {name: 'Tom', s: true}, {name: 'Oliver', s: true}, {name: 'Mark', s: true} ]
  }
]

/**
The function compares every element in the array (except the first one) to the first one 
and returns an array of elements with joined Id and common names
*/
const process = (arr) => {
  // Get the first element of the array
  const firstElem = arr[0];
  // Get all the other elements
  const otherElemes = arr.slice(1);
  
  // Loop over every element and transform it
  const returnElems = otherElemes.map(otherElem => ({
    // Make the id to be a String of unique ids
    // 1. Concat Id of first elment and current element
    // 2. Split the Ids to make an array out of them
    // 3. Create Set from Array to remove duplicates
    // 4. Join it back to a string
    id: [...new Set(`${firstElem.id}|${otherElem.id}`.split('|'))].join('|'),
    // Names are all names that are also contained in the names from the firstElement
    names: otherElem.names.filter(currName => {
      return firstElem.names.filter(fName => fName.name == currName.name).length > 0
    })
  }));
  
  // If there are still more than 1 elments in the array left, process the processed array again
  if(returnElems.length == 1)
    return returnElems;
  else
    return process(returnElems);
}

console.log(process(singles));
```

Comment: Nice code but with my 3000~ elements array it's giving an error

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)

at line const returnElems = otherElemes.map((otherElem) => {

Comment: What does your data actually look like then? @KrystianK 3000 elements in the outer  array or 3000 elements in the `names` array? Can you eventually send us the actual data?

Comment: 3000 elements in "single" array, then each of "names" inside contains from 2 to 20-30 elements